# How to count number of identical, sequential values in a column with python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, series

Say I have a dataframe such as:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1]})
```

I'd like to count the number of time the current column value has been seen in a row previous. For the above example, the output would be:

```py
[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

I know how to group by and cumulative sum all repeating values, but I don't know how to get it to restart at each new value.

i.e.

```py
df['A'].groupby(df['A']).cumcount() 
# returns [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3] which is not what I want.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this method:

```
df.groupby((df['A'] != df['A'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    3
6    1
7    2
dtype: int64
```

#### Details

Use equality to check between current row and next row, then `cumsum` to create a new group for each changing in 'A', then `groupby` and `cumcount` adding 1 to start at 1 instead of zero.

#### Break down into steps

Broken up in steps so you can see the progression in the dataframe columns.

```
df['grp'] = df['A'] != df['A'].shift() 
#for numbers you can use df['A'].diff().ne(0) 
#however using inquality check is more versatile for strings
df['cumgroup'] = df['grp'].cumsum()
df['count'] = df.groupby('cumgroup').cumcount() + 1
df
```

Output:

```
   A    grp  cumgroup  count
0  1   True         1      1
1  1  False         1      2
2  2   True         2      1
3  3   True         3      1
4  3  False         3      2
5  3  False         3      3
6  1   True         4      1
7  1  False         4      2
```